# ajax update div

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Controller action:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        ViewData["sample"] = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        return View();
    }
```

View page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Index</h2>

<div id="divId"><%= Html.Encode(ViewData["sample"])%></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">var event = new Object(); $get("panelOneForm").onsubmit();</script>
 <%using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Proba", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "divId" }, new { id = "panelOneForm" })) { } %>

</asp:Content>
```

I try to make auto update View but failed. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define an invisible submit button inside the form:

```
<div id="divId"></div>

<%using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Proba", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "divId" })) { %>
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" style="display:none;" />
<% } %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Make sure you put this script after the form
    // so that the button is loaded into the DOM before
    // manipulating it
    $get("btnSubmit").click();
</script>
```

Also the `Index` action on the `Proba` controller  that you are invoking asynchronously needs to return only a partial view or directly some content. Notice that `ViewData` is no longer used neither in the controller action nor in the resulting div:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // You probably want to remove the next line before shipping your
    // application in production as it is not good to stall the thread for 3s
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    return Content(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), "text/plain");
}
```

Comment: I try with your code but problem is still there, date and time not update automaticaly

Comment: This $get("btnSubmit").click(); click only one time,  why

Comment: @Ognjen, maybe because you are calling it only once.

Comment: How will I adjust to call every 10 seconds ie auto refresh

Comment: By using the `setInterval` function: `window.setInterval(function() { $get("btnSubmit").click(); }, 10000);`

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the microsoft ajax libraries ?

```
<script src="/Content/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Content/MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

here is a [tutorial](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCPreview4UsingAjaxAndAjaxForm.aspx). Do you have firebug? If so, try to see if the libraries are loaded correctly, and no errors where detected while executing

Comment: I have this error on MisrosoftAjax.debug.js: Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Object of type 'Sys._Application' cannot be converted to type 'Sys._Application'. Parameter name: instance
[Break on this error] if (!this.isInstanceOfType(instanc...e', Object.getType(instance), this);

Comment: Do you have any other ajax in the page that is making a call ? Have you referenced the script in your web.config ?

Comment: I referenced script in site.master

Comment: In web.config I have this: <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Linq" />
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
      </namespaces>

Comment: it is strange that you are having this in mvc. I can't figure it out. I would use jquery, sorry